# lapply and multiple conditional arguments (ifelse versus if else series)

Tags: r, controls, lapply

I have a list of dataframes:

```
count1<-(seq(1:10)) 
count2<-(seq(5:14))    
other<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j")
a<-seq(1,20,by=2)
b<-seq(1,30,by=3)
c<-seq(1,40,by=4)

df1<-data.frame(cbind(a,other,count1))
df2<-data.frame(cbind(b,other,count1))
df3<-data.frame(cbind(c,other,count2))

sept<-list(df1,df2,df3)
```

I want to create an additional variable in each dataframe with values conditional on the value of count1/count2. With lapply, ifelse works for two conditions:

```
sept2<-lapply(sept,function(x) {
     mx<-max(x[[3]]);
     d3<-(mx-2);
     ifelse (d3 < x[[3]], x[[4]] <-4, x[[4]] <-0);
 })

this2
[[1]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4

[[3]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4
```

However, using the same basic structure with an if else series doesn't work.

```
this3<-lapply(this,function(x) {
    mx<-max(x[[3]]);
    d3<-(mx-2);
    d2<-(mx-4);
    d1<-(mx-6);
    if (d3<x[[3]] && x[[3]]<=mx) {
        x[[4]] <-4
    } else if (d2<x[[3]] && x[[3]]<=d3){
        x[[4]] <-3
        } else if (d1<x[[3]] && x[[3]]<=d2){
            x[[4]] <-2
        }else {
            x[[4]] <-1
        }
})

this3

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

I don't understand why R knows to apply the function to each observation of x[[3]] when using ifelse, but not when using an if else series. Why are these two situations different?

Comment: `count2 <- (seq(5:15))` is too long. may be `count2 <- (seq(5:14))`

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, when you write a `if(cond) {do1} else {do2}`, only the first element in `cond` is evaluated. For example, if `cond[1] == TRUE`, then `do_1` is executed, and `do2` if it's `FALSE`. Remaining elements of `cond` are disregarded.

That's not the behaviour of `ifelse`, as you've noticed from the first example. In `ifelse (cond, do1, do2)`, relevant parts in `do1` and `do2` will be done depending on which elements of `cond` are `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

---

Following code shoud do what you want

```
this <- sept 
this3 <-lapply(this, function(x) {
  mx <- max(x[[3]]);
  d3 <- mx-2
  d2 <- mx-4
  d1 <- mx-6
  x[[4]] <- rep(1, length(x[[3]]))
  x[[4]][d3<x[[3]] & x[[3]]<=mx] <- 4
  x[[4]][d2<x[[3]] & x[[3]]<=d3] <- 3
  x[[4]][d1<x[[3]] & x[[3]]<=d2] <- 2
  x[[4]]
})
```

Comment: But I have if (cond) {do1} else if (cond2) {do2} else {do3}. R can handle an if else series in other contexts, but not here.

Comment: What happens with if (cond) {do1} else if (cond2) {do2} else {do3} is same as what happens with if (cond) {do1} else else {do2}. If cond is a vector only the first element cond, that is cond[1], is TRUE then do1 is done, and so on.

Comment: Behaviour of ifelse is different. In `ifelse(cond, do_true, do_false)`, if cond[1] is TRUE do_true[1], so to speak, is executed, if cond[1] is FALSE do_false[1] is performed. Then looks at cond[2] and either do_true[2] or do_false[2] get done, and so on.

Comment: You can see the behaviour of if (cond) {} else {} by changing some of the values. For example `[[2]]$count1[1] <- 10` see what happens...

Comment: Another way to say this is that in if (cond) {} else {},  the cond is assumed to be of length one. Even if not, only the first element cond[1] is used. In ifelse, cond can be a scaler or a vector.

Comment: I've edited the answer and gave an approach to do what you wanted to do.